# Active filter design using a design tool

Tags: active-filter

After a previous question I decided to make an active LP filter by using Analog Device's [filter design tool](https://www.analog.com/designtools/en/filterwizard/). I found a +/-15V dual supply so I want to use it to power the filter. I'm quite new in using this tool and first I set the desired values for the passband and stop band and chose 4 stage 8th order Butterworth Bessel. One of the reason is that I noticed if I set like this the flatness of the passband does not overshoot with different tolerances. So here is the basic settings:

[image]

Then it shows the Bode diagrams for selected component tolerances:

[image]

And below is the group delay:

[image]

And it suggests LT1007 as a low noise opamp and here is the whole circuit:

[image]

I'm not going to solder this on a PCB but on a [stripboard](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/518qR5q%2BtAL._SR600%2C315_PIWhiteStrip%2CBottomLeft%2C0%2C35_PIAmznPrime%2CBottomLeft%2C0%2C-5_PIStarRatingFOURANDHALF%2CBottomLeft%2C360%2C-6_SR600%2C315_ZA(18%20Reviews)%2C445%2C291%2C400%2C400%2Carial%2C12%2C4%2C0%2C0%2C5_SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg) or euroboard. And if so far there's no fatal mistake in the design, I'm completely blank about two points.

1. How can the group delay plot be interpreted? Does it matter in this
   filter application if the input is not a pulse but a varying analog
   signal? I don't know how to interpret that plot and whether I need
   to make any adjustment.
2. The tool is suggesting me four pieces of [LT1007](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1007-LT1037.pdf). There is also
   [LT1125](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/11245ff.pdf) which is very similar(maybe the same) to LT1007(¿). Is it
   better in terms of noise or another issue to use a quad opamp rather
   than four pieces of opamp? (Or a cheaper LM324 would be adequate for this filter?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94300/discussion-on-question-by-cm64-some-questions-about-an-active-filter-design-usin).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Comment: @DaveTweed Hi Dave, how did you move it to chat? How could I have moved it to chat. See [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/please-avoid-extended-discussions-in-comments-would-you-like-to-automatically-m) question on Meta.

Comment: @Neil_UK: I'm a moderator. We have tools that will move any comments to chat. I don't know why the regular tool isn't working for you.